# want two sum function side bye side filter by transaction type with distinct party name

Tags: mysql

i have this table

| Party Name | transaction type | Ammount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | send | 2000 |
| xyz | recived | 1000 |
| Abc | send | 2000 |
| xyz | send | 2000 |
| Abc | recived | 3000 |
| xyz | recived | 2000 |
| Abc | send | 2000 |

want this output

| Party Name | total recievedAmount | total send |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 3000 | 6000 |
| xyz | 3000 | 2000 |

Comment: Use conditional aggregation: `SUM(CASE WHEN x='xxx' THEN y ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Akina suggested, using conditional aggregation will do the trick:

```
select `party name`, 
sum(case when `transaction type`='recived' then ammount else 0 end) as 'total recievedAmount', -- please check if the column name ammount and string value recived are typos
sum(case when `transaction type`='send' then ammount else 0 end) as 'total send' 
from your_table 
group by `party name` ;
```